# Save on disk and reload estimates for esttab

Tags: stata

Is there any way to save and reload data in between an `eststo` command and an `esttab`?

What I would love is something like the following:

```
eststo: quietly reg a b
estsave using foo.est, replace

***

*Some other File
estload using foo.est
esttab foo.tex
```

Any other alternatives that let me play with the way I output regressions by trial and error (without having to re-run them and having to be at an interactive prompt) would be enormously helpful.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider up-voting it with the upper arrow and accepting it using the check-mark.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to put it to disk?

The (prefix) command `eststo` stores the results in memory until you close the file, and unless specified names each estimate consecutively (`eststo1`, `eststo2` etc.). You can re-program and re-run only part of the `do` file.

Alternatively, you could create all estimates in a `do` and call it from a secondary `do`:

```
/* .do for make tables */
do makeEstimates.do
esttab ...
```

Elsewhere you program `makeEstimates.do`:

```
/* .do to make estimates */
quietly regress a b
estout ab
```

You can run once, then comment out the `do makeEstimates.do` line to just work on `estout` if you do not change them.

Comment: As I said, because I'm not doing this interactively. Sometimes the layout changes don't become apparent until the next day or until a more senior researcher has feedback, a day or week later.

Answer (score 2):

You can store estimates on disk with the `estimates save` command:

```
sysuse auto, clear

quietly regress price mpg
estimates save foo1

quietly regress price trunk
estimates save foo2

quietly regress price weight
estimates save foo3
```

The above code snippet creates `3` files in your current working directory containing the estimates:

```
foo1.ster
foo2.ster
foo3.ster
```

You can then reload these and use them with `esttab` non-interactively and in any way you like with the `estimates use` command:

```
estimates use foo2
esttab .

----------------------------
                      (1)   
                    price   
----------------------------
trunk               216.7** 
                   (2.81)   

_cons              3183.5** 
                   (2.87)   
----------------------------
N                      74   
----------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

```
estimates use foo1
esttab .

----------------------------
                      (1)   
                    price   
----------------------------
mpg                -238.9***
                  (-4.50)   

_cons             11253.1***
                   (9.61)   
----------------------------
N                      74   
----------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

```
estimates use foo3
esttab .

----------------------------
                      (1)   
                    price   
----------------------------
weight              2.044***
                   (5.42)   

_cons              -6.707   
                  (-0.01)   
----------------------------
N                      74   
----------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```